# React Native fetch with cookie problems

Tags: react-native, cookies

I am re-writing a small app in React Native as a learning exercise. I am pulling data from a server for which I have a cookie. The cookie is hard-coded in my apps, no handshaking required. The same cookie works in other (iOS) versions of this small app, and repeated uses of the cookie are fine and the server responds with the requested data. I do not own this server.

In the React Native iOS version, the first call works but subsequent calls fail with a 401. I'm trying to understand A) why only the first call works and B) how to change the code to work every time.

Here's the call (modified to protect the server, etc, blah blah)

```
const onFetchPressed = async () => {
     try {
       const urlString = blahblah
       const response = await 
       fetch(urlString, {
         method: 'GET',
         credentials: 'include',
         headers: {
           "Host": "blahblah",
           "Accept": "application/json",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
           "User-Agent": "blahblah",
           "Connection": "keep-alive",
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Cookie": "session_id=shhh-secret-stuff-here"
         },
      });
      const json = await response.json();
      setUsers(json);
      console.debug(json)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
  }
}
```

Reading as much as I can on this, it seems perhaps I need to use "Set-Cookie" and specify "Same-Site" = none ? I'm at a loss on how to implement that, however.

Comment: Set-Cookie is set by the server in the response header. Since you've mentioned that you "do not own the server", you cannot change the cookie.

Comment: @TBA I am not looking to change the cookie, but to force React Native to send the cookie with every request. If Set-Cookie won't work, do you know of another way to do this?